# How to serialize a list of non model/queryset objects

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework, wagtail-apiv2

I am looking for a proper way to be able to pass a manually created list of objects to Wagtail API.

The list is coming from an imported function which simply generates the following list.

List (not a queryset or model instance)

```py
data = [ {"id":"1","name":"John"}, {"id":"2","name":"Jack"}, {"id":"3","name":"Jim"} ]
```

I might have done it wrong but I have added a simple property of no type in the model:

```py
from external_source import generate_data


class MyModel(BaseContentPage):
  ...
  data = generate_data()

  ...
  api_fields = (
    ...
    + [
      APIField(data)
    ]
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Create SerializerMethodField in your Serializer Class:

```
some_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
```

and then create a function get_some_list(self):

```
def get_some_list(self):
      data = #some code or logic
       return data
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to include the error messages you get. But my first guess, based off the code you shared, is **missing quotes**.
Refactor your code like below and you are good to go:

```py
class MyModel(BaseContentPage):
  ...
  data = generate_data()

  ...
  api_fields = (
    ...
    + [
      APIField("data")
    ]
  )
```